# Which particles could be waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, waves

Which particles could be waves?
Electrons and photons are both particles and waves (electricity and electromagnetic radiation).
Could other fermions or bosons be both particles and waves?

Comment: [All of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave).

Comment: All quantum objects have wave particle duality

Answer (score 5):

Electrons and photons are neither particles nor waves. They are quantum-mechanical entities which exhibit properties that we may sometimes ascribe to classical particles, and sometimes to classical waves. But they are **not** classical particles, and they are not classical waves; and, most importantly, they are **not** sometimes classical particles and sometimes classical waves. They are quantum-mechanical objects **all the time**.

This being said, all aspects of reality are, as far as we know, accurately described by the laws of quantum mechanics, and therefore, **all objects are quantum**, so to speak. In this sense, we could say, as rob mentions in the comments, that **all particles** are waves (with the qualification from the previous paragraph).